# js function always returns null

Tags: javascript

This function always returns null...

```
function find1(arry, uid){
    arry.forEach(function(obj){
        if(obj.uid === uid){
            return obj;
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

but when I change it to below code, it works...

```
function find2(arry, uid){
    var dt;
    arry.forEach(function(obj){
        if(obj.uid === uid){
            dt = obj;
        }
    });
    return dt;
}

var array = [
    {uid:"name01"},
    {uid:"name02"},
    {uid:"name04"},
    {uid:"name04"}
];


console.log('find1', find1(array, 'name02'));   // console output: find1 null
console.log('find2', find2(array, 'name02'));   // console output: find2 Object {uid: "name02"}
```

what am I doing wrong in `find1`?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return values of `forEach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In find1 method you are explicitly returning `null`. And in `forEach` loop on arry value, it does not return from the `find1` method, it returns from the anonymous function the inside `forEach` for all the values in array.

Comment: my bad, I assumed that that return would act as return for ```find1```, forgot that it was inside anonymous function...

Answer (score 0):

In first example you return return from internal function, not from function 'find1'. The result returns from internal function to body of 'find1'. But 'find1' doesn't return this result.

To fix it you only need a variable in function 'find1'. Like so:

```
var result = array.forEach(...);
return result;
```

Or so:

```
var result = null;
arry.forEach(function(obj){
        if(obj.uid === uid){
            result = obj;
        }
    });
return result;
```

Comment: sorry, but ```var result = array.forEach(...);``` the result would hold value ```undefined```